# repeated lines when I use char[] in while loop for reading text file in Android

Tags: java, android

I use char[] as a buffer to restore the text BufferedReader reads.
and with while loop I read all the text file 200 chars per loop until it hits -1.
This is my code.

```
    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    String line;
    char[] buffer=new char[200];
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
    InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bfr= new BufferedReader(isr);
    try {
        String s="";
        while(true)
        {   int temp= bfr.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            if(temp<0)
                break;
            else s=s+new String(buffer);
            }
        textView.setText(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But my result came out wring.
It repeat the last 100 chars two times.
I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s=s+new String(buffer);
```

That should be

```
s=s+new String(buffer, 0, temp);
```

You're ignoring the count returned by `read()`. You should probably also add a charset parameter.

But you shouldn't read entire files into memory. Process it a piece at a time.